# What is this tall tree with narrow leaves and sweet red fruit?

Tags: identification, trees

This 7 m (23 ft) tall tree has been growing over my deck for some time, and I've ignored it until I saw a [Tui](http://nzbirdsonline.org.nz/species/tui) eating its fruit the other day. I'm in Wellington NZ.

My landscape designer didn't know what it was when in flower, but I guess the native birds do know so maybe it's a native.

Picture from the deck
[image: tree]

Fruit with leaves, it's sweet
[image: leaves and fruit]

And cut fruit with seeds
[image: cut fruit]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like [Cornus Kousa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_kousa) luckily an edible fruit if you tried it before asking!

Comment: Great! And I found a muffin recipe for it that I'll try www.lessnoise-moregreen.com/2013/09/foraging-for-kousa-dogwood-berries-and.html?m=1

Comment: We have a few of these growing in Connecticut as well.

Comment: I am glad to learn what it is too, I had no idea what it was because it looks a lot like a dogwood that bears lychi fruits. I wouldn't have known they were edible.