# What is the name of this fruit?

Tags: fruits

> [image]
>   It is about 2 cm diameter, pale red, with plenty of small bosses. The inside is soft, sweet and orange.

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/24048/1894

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some type of dogwood fruit. Perhaps even Kousa Dogwood (Cornus kousa), which according to http://eattheplanet.org/dogwood-tree-flowers-fruit/, "are edible and one of tastiest and prolific wild edibles that can be found in the landscape." They have a picture of it that looks a lot like your fruit:

[image]

Comment: Are there similar species with the same kind of fruit?